# Visual Studio not find resource image path for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm working with Visual Studio 2019 and .NET 4.6.
The my projects image source path with resources dll file.
Example:`Source="/ViennaResources;Component/Images/onlyAudioIcon.png"`
The visual studio 2010! (with .net 4) and 2022 no problem. The problem is VS 2019 and 2017. (the vs 2019 hint "not found C:\ViennaResources...")
Why not found the image resource VS 2019 and 2017?
[image: Visual Studio 2019]
[image: Visual Studio 2022]

Comment: Could you share your project or dll using onedirve or github? Or you tell us the steps to reproduce, otherwise it will be difficult to move forward.

Comment: Hello!
Share my example project:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArNldr4ZDAGChXW45RIE49u5NKNv?e=hsbz00

Comment: I did test your project as you said. It is recommended that you could report the problem in the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home).

Comment: Thank you. Feedback the problem the MS.
(not for nothing I like the Visual Studio 2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft answer:
As a workaround you can use absolute URI instead of a relative one, e.g.

absolute URI: Source="pack://application:,,,/MyLib;Component/Images/logo.png"

relative URI: Source="/MyLib;Component/Images/logo.png"